# Imitate "cat >" command in c (LINUX/UNIX)

Tags: c, shell, unix, command

I need to imitate the command: "cat > " using c with exec family.

I cant find a way to do it because it doesn't recognize the symbol '>', I've already tried using execlp but maybe my syntax is wrong.

Thanks for the help! appreciated.

Comment: It’s a feature of the shell, so you’ll have to run the command through a shell for it to work

Comment: See `man dup2`.

Comment: it's finally imitating or running "cat >"?

Comment: Hey @Slawomir Dziuba and @ oguz ismail thanks alot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command is `cat`. The `>` is interpreted by the shell, redirecting the stdout of the command to a specific file.

Thus, you would need to connect the stdout (file descriptor 1) of the process running `cat` to a file:

```
/* emulating `cat >file` */
int fd = open("file", …);
/* use our own fd 1 */
dup2(fd, 1);
close(fd);
/* with new stdout, exec `cat` */
exec("cat");
```